# How to use keys mentioned in env on the server if env files arent pushed on to git

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have written an env file which has a few urls but, as most of the people on the forums suggest not to push the env files to git a question was bugging me. How would my application on the server fetch the key values which iam using.

Comment: You set them in the actual server environment, as real env vars. The point of things like `.env` is to _simulate_ that for local development.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so you mean to say I need to use variables storing those values to replace env files when it comes to server

Comment: It's exactly what he means. However, how to implement it server-side largely depends on what you use in your production environment. @jonrsharpe suggests you set it on the ENV of the OS you're using server-side, but you can also set them via helm charts if you're using K8s, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your env variables on the hosting server itself, Here's how we add that in `vercel`.

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables

[image]

And if someone else from your team wants to run the app on their local machine then you need to send them the `.env` file separately.